# New Bicycle - Brakes Squeak

Tags: brakes

I just bought a new Schwinn Cutter, but my brakes are constantly squeaking when I apply them. It has nothing to do with weather as I haven't taken it out in the rain. The rims on the bike do have some colored trim, but I'm not sure if that's the reason. Any ideas on reducing the break squeaking as it's embarrassing?

Follow up: these are not disk brakes.

Comment: Take it to the shop where you bought it.  The brakes need a simple adjustment.

Answer (score 4):

Take the new bike to the bike shop where you purchased it and ask for the brake pads to be adjusted. They may need some break in time/miles, but usually an adjustment of the brake pads so that the front of the pad makes contact with the wheel first, will keep the pads from squealing when used. We're talking millimeters in difference...hardly noticeable at all with the front of the brake pad being closer to the wheel. This reduces the vibration you're hearing.